# The truth value of a series is ambiguous, when I made a calculation on a loop on Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, series

I have the following loop:

```
max_potential = 100
for indx, values in geography.sort_values(district)[neighborhood].items():
    population = geography_clusters[geography_clusters['neighborhood']==indx]['potential'].astype(int)
    potential_neighborhood = potential_neighborhood + population 
    if potential_neighborhood < max_potential:
        list_close_neighborhood.append(indx)
```

And I get the following error

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

on this part of the code:

```
if potential_neighborhood < max_potential:
```

I believe that as the input is a series, I can't make a conditional based on the whole series. What I want to do is mainly save the value of each neighborhood (that works as an index in the loop) if that row
satisfies the following condition:

```
if potential_neighborhood < max_potential:
```

And append the [neighborhood] value on a list [list_close_neighborhood]. Is it possible?

Comment: You are comparing multiple numbers, a`pd.Series`, to a single element `max_potential`. Since the series contains multiple numbers, you need to specify if you want to have ALL or ANY of those numbers to be smaller than `max_potential`. What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean by a subset? Please make a [mre] including some example input(s), desired output, and complete but minimal code. For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). You are using Pandas, right? Please add the tag for it or whatever library you're using. For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: Hi @wjandrea. What I want to do is mainly be able to store a value based on [potential_neighborhood] (a value calculated in every iteration) and append it to a list. That's what I meant by "subset". Sorry, english is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a link to a popular question that should help you. It’s still out of my grasp but I get what you’re trying to do and I think the answers here will help you fix it without over complicating. Please let me know if I’m wrong!

[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o?rq=2)

Comment: Hi @LaurenKai. What I want to do is mainly be able to store a value based on [potential_neighborhood] (a value calculated in every iteration) and append it to a list. That's what I meant by "subset". Sorry, english is not my native language. Do you think it is possible to achieve?